# Programatically Update FTP account quota in cPanel?

Tags: php, http, ftp, cpanel

I am trying to update the quota of a cPanel FTP account through php.

```
https://username:password@mydomain.com:2083/frontend/x3/ftp/doeditquota.html?acct=mailid@mydomain.com&quota=50
```

I am making a HTTP Request with the above URL.

And I getting response message

> The FTP account maildid@mydomain.com was successfully modified with a new quota of 50 Megabytes. 0Failed to determine FTP maildid@mydomain.com directory.

But in server quota is not updated . Actually whats issue?

And why this message :

> 0Failed to determine FTP maildid@mydomain.com directory.

Comment: are you aware that cpanel has a vast api library that allows you to do this properly? http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/ApiDocs/Api2/ApiFtp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution.

https://username:password@mydomain.com:2083/frontend/x3/ftp/doeditquota.html?acct=mailid&quota=50

remove domain from the 'acct' parameter.